# Powershell, send email for each user that has been disabled to their managers

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, active-directory

So after a-lot of help, there is a script that will search users that were disabled for the past 14 days + show their managers name + email and date when they were disabled:

```
$ou = "my-ou"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$todaydate = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
$disabledAccounts = Get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $false -and Modified -ge $date } -SearchBase $ou -Properties Modified,manager | select samaccountname,Modified,manager
#$ManagerName = ''
$Body = ”
<html>
<body>
<p>Dear $ManagerName,<br>
The user $userName has been disabled on $todaydate .<br
</body>
</html>”

ForEach($disabledAccount in $disabledAccounts){

$manager = get-aduser -property emailaddress,DisplayName $disabledAccount.manager
$ManagerName= $manager.Displayname
$userName = $disabledAccount.samaccountname
Send-MailMessage -To $manager.UserPrincipalName -From ‘test@email.com’ -Subject ‘Disabled account’ -Body $Body -SmtpServer ‘mysmtp’ -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
}
```

The problem for now that this script only sent email for 1 user when in my test i have 2 disabled users in this period of time.
And the first command with "Get-Aduser" i see both of the users, and in the second one "Get-aduser" i see only 1.

Comment: *no matter how I try* - show us how you're trying. We can't see your screen.

Comment: You're currently searching for accounts changed more than _14 days into the future_ - change `(Get-Date).AddDays(14)` to `(Get-Date).AddDays(-14)`

Comment: @alex Please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64770362/edit), code in comments is not very readable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done.

Comment: And what happens? Does it throw an error? 0 results? Some results but not all? More results than expected? Or do you just need help sending the email?

Comment: I'm not getting any results(any email) and no errors.

Comment: There's a third `Get-ADUser`-line that's preventing the emails from being sent (assuming you used most of the script you're referring to). This part in particular needs some love `If( $userDetails.accountExpires -eq 0 -or $userDetails.accountExpires -eq 9223372036854775807 ) { $sendEmail = $false }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ou = "my ou direction"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$diabledAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false -and Modified -ge $date } -SearchBase $ou -Properties Modified,manager | select samaccountname,Modified,@{n='Manager';e={(Get-ADUser $.manager).name}},@{n='ManagerEmail';e={(Get-ADUser $.manager -properties mail).mail}}

ForEach($diabledAccount in $diabledAccounts){
    Send-MailMessage -To $diabledAccount.ManagerEmail -Subject 'Disabled account' -Body "Account $diabledAccount.samaccountname has been disabled in the last 14 days" -SmtpServer '' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a-lot, but now i have an email message issue with showing the manager names and user names.
Take a look on my first post i Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something like this on Spice works

```
$ou = “my_ou”
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$disabledAccounts = Get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $false -and Modified -ge $date } -SearchBase $ou -Properties Modified,manager | select samaccountname,Modified,manager
$ManagerName = ''
$Body = ”
<html>
<body>
<p>Dear $ManagerName,<br>
The user $userName has been disabled on .<br
</body>
</html>”

ForEach($disabledAccount in $disabledAccounts){

$manager = get-aduser -property emailaddress,DisplayName $disabledAccount.manager 
$ManagerName= $manager.Displayname
$userName = $disabledAccount.samaccountname
Send-MailMessage -To $manager.ManagerEmail -From ‘myemail@’ -Subject ‘Disabled account’ -Body $Body -SmtpServer ‘mysmtp server’ -BodyAsHtml -Priority High
}
```

Comment: I changed "ManagerEmail" to "UserPrincipalName" and it's works, but it's sending to only 1 user manager..
And when I'm running the second "Get-Aduser"command in "ForEach", the output i see is only 1 manager information and not 2 as expected for my test.
Because the first variable "disabledAccounts" shows me 2 users with 2 different managers and emails.